How to change token_type from "bearer" to "Bearer" in Keycloak's /token response?
I'm using Keycloak 21.0.0 i try to apply authentication with signed JWT tokens. When I invoke the /token endpoint, the response contains a token_type field with the value "bearer". However, I need this value to be "Bearer"instead.
Here is the default AuthorizationResponse class from Keycloak that seems to control the token_type value:
public class AuthorizationResponse extends AccessTokenResponse {

private boolean upgraded;

public AuthorizationResponse() {
}

public AuthorizationResponse(AccessTokenResponse response, boolean upgraded) {
    setToken(response.getToken());
    setTokenType("Bearer");
    setRefreshToken(response.getRefreshToken());
    setRefreshExpiresIn(response.getRefreshExpiresIn());
    setExpiresIn(response.getExpiresIn());
    setNotBeforePolicy(response.getNotBeforePolicy());
    this.upgraded = upgraded;
}

public boolean isUpgraded() {
    return upgraded;
}

public void setUpgraded(boolean upgraded) {
    this.upgraded = upgraded;
}

}
{"access_token":"eyJhbG..",
"token_type":"bearer",
...
}


Considering that every associated specification use the term "Bearer", I think you'll have a hard time convincing them to change to "bearer", just because you "need" it that way.

@forty-two Actually, I misunderstood the issue. The Keycloak token endpoint response JSON has an improper token_type='bearer' and it should it be 'Bearer'?

Very strange if that's the case. Could it be a configuration problem? I'm afraid my non-existent Keycloak experience is not of help here. Do you have any filtering mechanism that might intefere?

@forty-two the solution is set Use lower-case bearer type in token responses to off

The question should be why it was enabled in the first case ;)

Sounds like a case of someone flipping the switch to 'on' without bothering to read the description :)

Right! And that would perhaps make you think that manual configuration is not a good idea. Go for automated scripted configuration from scratch.

For Keycloak 21, select your client, go to the Advanced tab, and set Use lower-case bearer type in token responses to off

